# How to bevel the corner of a block div?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Тег DIV</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .block1 { 
                width: 200px; 
                background: #ccc;
                padding: 5px;
                padding-right: 20px; 
                border: solid 1px black; 
                float: left;
            }
        </style> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="block1">Text Content</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

How do I describe the style to get the following?
[image]

Comment: you can either generate a triangle as naivists said, otherwise use table structures and images..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Until CSS4 `border-corner-shape` property [is in danger!](http://lea.verou.me/2013/03/border-corner-shape-is-in-danger-and-you-can-help/) and [it's not implemented](http://leaverou.github.io/border-corner-shape/), This can be done by using CSS3 transforms (to keep `border` property free for further usage):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="box">
  Text Content
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.box {
  width: 200px; 
  height: 35px;
  line-height: 35px;
  padding: 0 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  padding-right: 20px;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-right: 0;  
  position: relative;
}

.box:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background-color: #ccc;
  border: solid 1px black;
  border-left: 0;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: -1px; /* pull it up because of 1px border */
  right: -17.5px; /* 35px / 2 */
  transform: skew(-45deg);
  -o-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: skew(-45deg);
  -webkit-transform: skew(-45deg);
}
```

Here is **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/onitod/1/edit)**.

**NOTE:** There's another `div` in example above has `class` attribute of `box2`, which implemented without using CSS3 declarations that you might consider using it ;)

Comment: **FYI:** `border-corner-shape` proposed as [`corner-shape`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-4/#corner-shaping) property in [CSS Backgrounds and Borders Module Level 4](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-backgrounds-4).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely it can be done using the inivisble border trick. There are some "triangle generators" on the web, for example, [this](http://apps.eky.hk/css-triangle-generator/) one

Comment: +1 This is the best option. You could use a additional `outline: solid 1px #000;` to create the outline from the image. Even around the triangle.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/DXWea/1/).

**The CSS and HTML:**

```css
    ul {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
      font: 14px Arial;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      list-style: none;
      text-align: center;
    }
    ul:before {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      z-index: -1;
      left: 124px;
      margin-left: -120px;
      width: 0;
      border-left: 0 solid transparent;
      border-right: 230px solid transparent;
      border-top: 179px solid #CCCCCC;
    }
    li {
      height: 3.8em;
      line-height: 3em;
      position: relative;
      margin-left: -562px;
    }
    li:after,
    li:before {
      content: "";
      display: block;
      height: 0.4em;
      background: #fff;
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Text Content</li>
</ul>
```

You have to use the `border-width` property to get your desired output.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If I describe a document like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Тег DIV</title>
  <style type="text/css">
   .block1 { 
    width: 300px;
    height: 0px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 200px 200px 0 0;
    border-color: #f200ff transparent transparent transparent;
   }
  </style> 
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="block1">Text Content</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I get almost what you need, but I do not understand why the text is not in the figure?