# Most efficient way to create a diagonal content box?

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I came across this neat little content box with this header :

[image: content box with diagonal line]

When I realized that it is similar to something I want to do on my website. Upon looking at the source I noticed they used an image rather than just CSS. I realize that I can use an image but this really defeats the efficiency. I was wondering if anyone knew how to do this through just plain CSS?

My attempt to do so ended with me not being able to bend the border. For example, here is what I tried:

```
<style>
 #container {
border: 1px solid black;
}
#header {
background: red;
border-top: 1px solid black;
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
border-left: 1px solid black;
}
#box {
padding: 10px;
}
</style>
<body>
<div id="container">
<span id="header">test</span>
<div id="box">
test
</div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, that looks nothing like how they did it. Also, I'm not even sure if it is good to use a span or not. But in this case, I think it is, because more content could be added to the right of the box rather than the div take up all the line (I think). Does anyone know a better way of doing it?

Comment: Have a look at: [How to bevel the corner of a block div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748387/how-to-bevel-the-corner-of-a-block-div/16748949#16748949).

Comment: @HashemQolami it is duplicate. voted to close.

Comment: Agreed, it's a duplicate. [Here is my take on it, anyways](http://jsbin.com/zosay/1/edit).

Comment: I don't think it is a duplicate. @HashemQolami 's answer gives a general approach for the issue but it doesn't provide the solution for the line on the top right and bottom left.

Comment: @web-tiki Fair enough. Reopened the topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use one pseudo element and border to create the lines :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/dd5rtprr/)**

output :

[image: box with angled border]

```css
span{
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:.5em 5em 1.5em .5em;
    border-top:1px solid #ccc;
    border-left:1px solid #ccc;
}
span:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute; 
    width:100%; height:100%;
    right:1em;bottom:1em;
    border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
    border-right:1px solid #ccc;
    
    webkit-transform-origin: 100% 0;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0;
    transform-origin:100% 0;
        
    webkit-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: skewX(-45deg);
    transform: skewX(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<span>FIND YOUR IMAGE</span><br/>
<span>short</span><br/>
<span>FIND YOUR IMAGE and another longer one</span><br/>
<span>FIND YOUR IMAGE and another longer one<br/>FIND YOUR IMAGE and another longer one</span>
```

Comment: I see that the transform rotated the border. It's a little confusing to me since I'm not used to this (Used to be good at CSS a while back) However, how would I turn it into a full content box?

Comment: @RickG. what do you mean by content box?

Answer (score 1):

Well I just made this, you use 1 element with a pseudo-element, may require some more tweaking!

```
#header {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: solid 1px gray;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}
#header:after {
    position: absolute;
    right:-17px;
    top:-7px;
    bottom:-8px;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0px;
    border-left:solid 1px gray;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(40deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(40deg);
    transform: rotate(40deg);
}
```

[image]

**[Check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/htrb5bL4/1/)**

More headers can be added beside each other by simply adding a left padding:

[image]

**[Check it out.](http://jsfiddle.net/htrb5bL4/2/)**