# Diagonal stripes and bars

Tags: css

I need to achieve two things. One is a Title bar that will hold a title and then end up with a diagonal right border and then also need a variable width diagonal pattern generated via CSS in this way (http://grab.by/DhPO). I've tried using various solutons, but most of them are generating the strip and diagonal cut via `border` properties which doesn't help much as it can't contain text unless I apply absolute positioning. Any smart way around this?

The most recent attempt is with http://jsfiddle.net/spdawson/HhZQe/light/  - however, I can't move the `tl` to the position of `tr` border. For the 2nd solution, I didn't yet find anything helpful and don't know how to approach it at all.

Comment: Hint: You can use `rotate` and `skew` with pseudo-elements. For a detailed answer, please show us what you have tried till now.

Comment: I haven't downvoted this, but it's getting downvotes because you haven't posted any code. Try posting the code that includes the 'border' properties you mentioned.

Comment: thanks, added all that I think is relevant and have currently

Comment: @GuitarMan: You can have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16748387/how-to-bevel-the-corner-of-a-block-div) for the first one (diagonal corner using skew). For the second, would your text always end within the blue part or can it extend? I would suggest using `linear-gradient`.

Comment: Thanks @Harry - Yes, I would aim to keep the text always in the blue section.

Comment: @GuitarMan: If you wish to keep the text within the blue section (and do a wrap-around when it exceeds the width) then `linear-gradient` may not be the best as the text will overflow. If the text is short enough to always fit within the blue section then it is fine. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9y5kw7vo/1/) is a sample for your reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a triangle on `:after` :pseudo-element for the first image and `linear-gradient` for the second image.

To get the cuts, the part of the `linear-gradient` have been set to `transparent`.

```css
body {
  background: url(http://www.lorempixel.com/600/400/sports/) no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
div {
  margin: 10px;
}
#one {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: #324660;
  color: #F5F4F4;
  font-size: 17px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
}
#one:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  right: -39px;
  top: 0;
  border-top: 50px solid #324660;
  border-right: 40px solid transparent;
}
#two {
  position: relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 50px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #324660, #324660 56%, #F96620 56%, #F96620 66%, #D1D7DB 66%, #D1D7DB 68%, transparent 68%, transparent 83%, #D1D7DB 83%, #D1D7DB 85%, #F96620 85%);
  color: #F5F4F4;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
span {
  font-size: 17px;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">1. Marketing:</div>
<div id="two"><span>Benefits</span> for facilities, therapists and patients</div>
```

Comment: wow - looks great! would this work as a responsive solution as well?

Comment: @GuitarMan - Yes, ofcourse. The color-stops are `percentage` units.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use diagonal gradients [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/k7osadoa/)

which was created using a [gradient generator](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

```css
.test {
  height: 50px;
  width: 200px;
  background: rgb(169, 3, 41);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)), color-stop(70%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1)), color-stop(80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1)), color-stop(80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1)), color-stop(81%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#04ed2f', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div class="test">Hello</div>
```

**Note**

this was a quick demo, and could (of course) be improved

---

Creating a header

---

```css
.test {
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 30px;
  background: rgb(169, 3, 41);
  /* Old browsers */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* FF3.6+ */
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1)), color-stop(60%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)), color-stop(70%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1)), color-stop(71%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1)), color-stop(72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1)), color-stop(80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1)), color-stop(80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1)), color-stop(81%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1)));
  /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(-45deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* IE10+ */
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(169, 3, 41, 1) 0%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 60%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 61%, rgba(109, 0, 25, 1) 70%, rgba(143, 2, 34, 1) 71%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 72%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 126, 219, 1) 80%, rgba(4, 237, 47, 1) 81%);
  /* W3C */
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#a90329', endColorstr='#04ed2f', GradientType=1);
  /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
.test:before {
  content: "header";
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="test">hello</div>
```

Comment: thank you - I will surely be able to use this!

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion an image is one solution.

A different solution is a gradient:

```css
#grad1 {
    height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left top, red , yellow); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom right, red, yellow); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom right, red, yellow); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, red , yellow); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<h3>Linear Gradient - Diagonal</h3>
<p>This linear gradient starts at top left. It starts red, transitioning to yellow:</p>

<div id="grad1"></div>

<p><strong>Note:</strong> Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions do not support gradients.</p>
```

But, maybe you would like this one:

```css
body {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: block;
     
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #4c4c4c; 
     
    height: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}

div {
     border: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
     border-top: 3px solid #4c4c4c;      
     padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
    <a href="#">New Music</a> 
    <div> 
        <h3> Hello, Everyone! </h3> 
        <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p> 
    </div>
```

Enjoy,
Giacomo

---

**UPDATE**

```css
body {
    background: #e3e3e3;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    width: 400px;
    margin: 100px auto;
}

a {
    padding: 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
     
    border-right: 30px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 30px solid #4c4c4c; 
     
    height: 0;
    line-height: 50px;
}

div {
     border: 1px solid #4c4c4c; 
     border-top: 3px solid #4c4c4c;      
     padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">New Music</a> 
    <div> 
        <h3> Hello, Everyone! </h3> 
        <p> 
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p> 
    </div>
```

The only change is:

```
display: inline-block;
```

Bye,
Giacomo

Comment: this looks great - thanks! any idea about the screen grab for variable width strips?

Comment: Hi @GuitarMan, just a moment: I update my answer. ;-)