# Create an Angled Color Banner

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

Hi I'm trying to create the following Angled Strip Look in HTML & CSS:

[image]

Just the Blue and Purple area with white after.

I can obviously see how to do it using an image but what about HTML/CSS only?

Is this possible?

Its used on the site - www.africa.dating

I know I should have more example code but I'm actually not sure where to begin so I only have the following HTML:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e2dr5udr/3/

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="blue"></div>
    <div id="purple"></div>
</div>

#container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
    position: absolute;
}

#blue {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    position: absolute;
} 

#purple {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: purple;
    position: absolute;
}
```

thankyou

Comment: If you know how to draw a trapezium with CSS, you'll know the answer

Comment: I remember seeing a couple of similar ones in the last week mate. Not accusing of lack of effort but did you happen o come across them?

Comment: have a look here http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/add-angled-designs-with-css-and-jquery/

Comment: Similar item (but only 2 pieces) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706119/css-shape-outside-firefox-browser-support

Comment: See my [answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27601802/3436942)

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/e2dr5udr/4/

Comment: @Harry: I remember answering another one, somewhat recently, too with a slightly different approach. Will look to see if I can dig that one up, too.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use a **pseudo element** and some **border manipulation**.

This would allow you to create it with only a single element, to create this:

```css
.title {
  height: 1px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 170px solid blue;
  border-right: 170px solid transparent;
  width: 190px;
  position:relative; 
}

.title:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height: 1px;
  top:0px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: 170px solid purple;
  border-right: 170px solid transparent;
  width: 210px;
  z-index:-1;
  }
```

```html
<div class="title"></div>
```

If you do not want to use this approach, an alternative method (using background gradients) can be viewed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27601802/3436942)

---

**Using SkewX:**

```css
div{
  position:relative;
  height:15vh;
  width:60vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  }
div:before{
  z-index:-1;
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  height:100%;
  right:50%;
  width:150%;
  border-right:10px solid green;
  background:cornflowerblue;
  -webkit-transform:skewX(45deg);
  transform:skewX(45deg);
  }
```

```html
<div>123</div>
```

Comment: np at. Just glad I could Help.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a demo of what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/shivanraptor/c4vrLrq7/

Basically it's a Square (`#blue`), Triangle (`#triangle`), Parallelogram (`#parallelogram`)

```css
    #container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: white;
        position: absolute;
    }
    
    #blue {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;
        background-color: blue;
        float: left;
    } 
    
    #triangle {
     width: 0;
     height: 0;
     border-left: 50px solid transparent;
     border-right: 50px solid transparent;
     border-bottom: 100px solid blue;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -50px;
        
    }
    #parallelogram {
     width: 50px;
     height: 100px;
     -webkit-transform: skew(30deg);
        -moz-transform: skew(30deg);
          -o-transform: skew(30deg);
     background: purple;
        float: left;
        margin-left: -50px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="container">
        <div id="blue"></div>
        <div id="triangle"></div>
        <div id="parallelogram"></div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want a `background-image`, you could make use of `rgba()` values and a :pseudo-element.

The idea is to apply the `background-image` to an `:after` :pseudo-element and the `linear-gradient` with `rgba()` values on the main `div`.

You could change the opacity of the `linear-gradient` by changing the alpha value in `rgba(red, green, blue, alpha)`

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(55deg, rgba(122, 0, 201, 0.8) 75%, rgba(178, 0, 204, 0.8) 75%, rgba(178, 0, 204, 0.7) 80%, transparent 80%);
}
div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/700/200);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

An other approach using one element, the `skewX()` property for the slope right side, the transparency is made with `rgba()` background-color and border on a pseudo element :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/yLu1sxmj/)**

```css
div{
    height:100%;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
div:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    top:0; right:0;
    width:100%; height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(90, 74, 199, .8);
    border-right:40px solid rgba(173, 96, 223, .8);
    
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 100%;
    transform-origin:100% 100%;
    
    -webkit-transform:skewX(30deg);
    -ms-transform:skewX(30deg);
    transform:skewX(30deg);
}


/******  FOR THE DEMO  *******/

html, body{
    background: url(http://lorempixel.com/output/people-q-c-640-480-1.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    margin:0;padding:0;
    height:100%;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: Like all the answers given so far but guess the choice would depend on other factors (like what other contents/text etc are present within the div). Border hack wouldn't make it easy to add text, gradients would make text overflow to the transparent/white are also.